# Check if file exists and copy it if it does

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching the net and have tried all the code found. My code should be simple but it's not working. I'm using a list to store image strings (but they do not have the extension on them). I want to test if the image file exists in a folder and if it does copy it. If it doesn't write to a file with the image name. The result I'm getting is all the files do not exists. But I checked and the files are there.

```
For Each image In GraphicList
    ImgFile = ImgLocation & "\" & image & ".*"
    Dim MoveFile As String
    MoveFile = createFigFolder & "\" & image & ".*"

    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(ImgFile) Then
        Debug.Write("File does not exists : " & ImgFile & vbCrLf)
        ' file does not exist
    Else
        Debug.Write("File EXISTS : " & ImgFile & vbCrLf)
        System.IO.File.Copy(ImgFile, MoveFile)
    End If
Next
```

Here's the code that writes the GraphicList

```
Private Sub CreateGraphicsFunction(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Regex = New Regex("infoEntityIdent=""(ICN.+?)[""].*?[>]")

    Dim ICNFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(MoveToPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each tFile In ICNFiles
        Dim input = File.ReadAllText(tFile)

        Dim match = Regex.Match(input)
        If match.Success Then
            GraphicList.Add(match.Groups(1).Value)
            Dim Regex2 = New Regex("<!ENTITY " & match.Groups(1).Value & "  SYSTEM ""(ICN.*?[.]\w.+)")
            Dim sysFileMatch = Regex2.Match(input)
            If sysFileMatch.Success Then
                ICNList.Add(sysFileMatch.Groups(1).Value)
                Debug.Write("found ICN " & sysFileMatch.Groups(1).Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

New Code to cycle through array and see if its entries match strings in Graphic Lists. This code doesn't work, but I think it's similar to what I want.

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(ImgLocation, ".*")
' Process the list of files found in the directory. '
Dim fileName As String

For Each fileName In fileEntries
    If ICNList.Contains(fileName) Then
        Debug.Write("File EXISTS : " & fileName & vbCrLf)
    Else
        Debug.Write("File does not exists : " & fileName & vbCrLf)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: File.Exist does not accept wildcards. You should use Directory.GetFiles

Comment: I looked at the directory.getfiles. Get's all the files in the folder with ".*", but how would I go about matching it to for image in GraphicList?

Comment: I've added the code for cycling through the files and seeing if it matches the list of strings in GraphicList. But it's not working. What am I missing? @EyIM

Comment: I think I've come a little closer. The GraphicList has strings of file names but they are missing the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the list of filenames on the source list of files, using the filename without extension as the key. Then iterate over the results and copy each one

```
Dim fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imgLocation).Join(
    graphicList, 
    Function(p) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p), 
    Function(f) f, 
    Function(p, f) p)

' create the directory first (does nothing if it already exists)
Directory.CreateDirectory(newLocation)

' copy each file
For Each fileName In fileNames
    System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(newLocation, Path.GetFileName(fileName)))
Next
```

Comment: I'm trying to write to a text file using If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then but I can't get to recognize the else Debug.Write(vbCr & "Missing file name in ELSE- " & fileName). I need this because not all the files found in fileName exists in the folder being searched on. What am I doing wrong? @djv